# How to prevent row aligining in grid geometry manager?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an Tk interface, that looks like this;

[image]

As you can see, I have 3 (4 if you count labels) columns. I want to have Entries (with their labels) not aligned with buttons on the right, because number of buttons and Entries will be different, and aligning them will look bad.

Also, I made the canvas span acroos multiple rows, so that Entries will stay on left of the canvas, but this caused large margins between Entries.

I have two related questions;

- Should I use pack geometry manager insted? If so, how?
- If grid would do this, how would I implement?

Here are my codes;

```
class Main(tk.Frame):

    w = 600
    h = 600

    def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent

        ### variables ###
        self.iterations = tk.StringVar()
        self.angle = tk.StringVar()
        self.axiom = tk.StringVar()
        self.rule1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.rule2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.rule3 = tk.StringVar()
        self.rule4 = tk.StringVar()
        self.constants = tk.StringVar()

        ### Labels ###
        tk.Label(self, text="Iterations").grid(column=0,row=0)
        tk.Label(self, text="angle").grid(column=0,row=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="axiom").grid(column=0,row=2)
        tk.Label(self, text="rule1").grid(column=0,row=3)
        tk.Label(self, text="rule2").grid(column=0, row=4)
        tk.Label(self, text="rule3").grid(column=0, row=5)
        tk.Label(self, text="rule4").grid(column=0, row=6)
        tk.Label(self, text="constants").grid(column=0, row=7)


        ### Entries ###
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.iterations).grid(column=1,row=0)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.angle).grid(column=1,row=1)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.axiom).grid(column=1,row=2)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.rule1).grid(column=1,row=3)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.rule2).grid(column=1, row=4)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.rule3).grid(column=1, row=5)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.rule4).grid(column=1, row=6)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.constants).grid(column=1, row=7)

        ### Render Button ###
        tk.Button(self, text="render", command=self.render_image).grid(column=0, row=8, columnspan=2)

        ### Preset Buttons ###
        tk.Button(self, text="Koch Snowflake", command=self.snowflake).grid(column=3, row=0)
        tk.Button(self, text="Custom 1", command=self.custom1).grid(column=3, row=1)

        ### Canvas ###
        self.cv = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.w, height=self.h, bg='white')
        self.cv.grid(column=2, rowspan=9, row=0)

        self.grid()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use frames in columns and then you can use different manager grid/pack/place in every frame

Beside you can get few frames with different buttons and show/hide frames to replace all buttons. (grid_forget/pack_forget/place_forget).

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? I am new to interface programming.

Comment: You have two columns (except canvas) in every column put `Frame` and put entries/labels in left frame and buttons in right frame. In left frame you can use `grid` or `pack` and in right frame you use separatly `grid` or `pack`

Comment: You can have `FrameA` with buttons `A`, `B` and `FrameB` with buttons `C`, `D`. If you need buttons `A`, `B` you hide `FrameB` (`grid_forget()`) and show `FrameA` (`grid()`), if you need buttons `C`, `D` you hide `FrameA` and show `FrameB`.